# Type of array index string or number?

Tags: typescript

when I loop over the indexes of an array they show up as string. But indexing an array using strings is forbidden. Isn't that incoherent? Why is it so?

```
for (const i in ["a", "b", "c"]) {
  console.log(typeof i + " " i + " " + arr[i]);  // -> string 0 'a', etc.
}
arr['0'] // ERROR ts7105: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number':
```

Comment: array's index is number? always has been

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in

Comment: Forbidden is an extreme word. I mean an array is an object so you can always do things like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhtBBLMBzA2gXRgF4ZcAiOMgGhjICNrbgz8BuAKAApEF4J4wATwCUAOgggAtgFMoACyzZiMAOQSZ8xSo4AzEL06hIsDDCzwkwmAG92MGEYkAbaaKchsnKIIAO0kDpmMADUtGGhpqFk4RYIuBj4wqz2APQpMAC0AHxoUJg4MAAMqnAqNLLAouwAvkA). It does however mean that when you iterate an array as an object all its indices are coerced into strings (which I agree is not intuitive)

Comment: It seems I couldn't make myself clear. My wondering is: Outside the for-in loop I am forced to use a number as index, e.g. `arr[0]`. But inside the loop, the index is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for ... in` iterates over the keys of the given object.

An array will have its indices as keys, see `Object.keys([4,5,1])` which prints `["0", "1", "2"]`.
To iterate a typed array use `for ... of`
See the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html). If you need the index use a regular `for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)` or `for(let [i,el] of arr.entries())` loop.

As for your question, yes it does seem incoherent, but it looks like indexing inside a loop using the loop variable allows string indices. But be aware that `index + 1` will be `"01"` because the index is a string.